# Running both Bundler and NPM on Heroku

Tags: ruby, node.js, heroku

I have a Node.js app that uses Compass, a Ruby gem.

When I push to Heroku it will detect a Node.js app and run `npm install`. Now, it detects the `Gemfile` first which it a ruby project and no longer runs `npm install`. Is it possible to tell Heroku this is a Node.js app which requires the `Gemfile` for running `bundle exec install compass`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a custom buildpack that supports both Ruby and Node. Take a look at [third-party buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/third-party-buildpacks) and [multi buildpacks](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi).